# How to edit the anonymous/default profile in firefox?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I am using Selenium to automate a test case where files are downloaded.
In Firefox, I get a dialog box to save or open the file when I click on the link to download the file. I went to Firefox and typed about:config in address bar and updated browser.helperapps.neverask.savetodisk with the mimetype. When I manually click on the link to download a file, it automatically downloads without dialog box. When I automate it with Selenium, the dialog box appears. Can anyone suggest a way to automate this in Firefox without creating a profile in code. I don't mind changing the browser setting. In Firefox how to update the profile which Selenium uses?

Comment: if creating profile in the code is the option...let me know how to do that
my code is as follows
@BeforeStory
    public void beforeStory() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Initializing WebDriver");
        driverProvider.initialize();
 webDriver = driverProvider.get();
webDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        //Specifies the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for an element if it is not immediately present.
        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting Firefox in Selenium WebDriver, it starts a new, anonymous profile you can modify it by creating a new profile and update preferences or using existing profile

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 

profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);

profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);

profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", **enter your download path**);

profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile",
            "text/csv, application/pdf, application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/x-excel,application/x-msexcel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml,application/excel");
    
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "text/csv, application/pdf, application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel, application/vnd.ms- excel,application/x-excel,application/x-msexcel,image/png,image/jpeg,text/html,text/plain,application/msword,application/xml,application/excel,text/x-c");

Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

If you don't wish to create a Firefox profile in the code then create a Firefox profile with the above settings manually and use that using the below code

```
ProfilesIni all_profiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = all_profiles.getProfile("created profile");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Hope this helps you....

Comment: @BeforeStory public void beforeStory() throws Exception { System.out.println("Initializing WebDriver"); 
driverProvider.initialize();
 webDriver = driverProvider.get();
 webDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); //Specifies the amount of time the driver should wait when searching for an element if it is not immediately present. webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: you have to put the code before creating an webdriver instance...In the above code i have created or used a firefox profile and passed it to FirefoxDriver class...